# Preparation of iodine solution

Tags: aqueous-solution

How to prepare $\mathrm{0.1M}$ $\ce{I_2}$ solution.
I have found in books that it should be prepared in $\ce{KI}$ solution but none of them explains why? Please explain in detail not just the procedure.

Answer (score 15):

Since $\ce{ I_2}$ is a non-polar covalent molecule, it does not ionize in water. It  cannot also be soluble in the polar water.

$\ce{KI}$, which is a polar, ionic compound, will ionize and dissolve in water. When KI dissolves in water, it ionizes to $\ce{K^+}$ and $\ce{I^-}$.

The $\ce{I^-}$ will react with $\ce{ I_2}$ to form the complex ion $\ce{I_3^-}$. $\ce{I_3^-}$ being negatively charged will dissolve in water.

Comment: And in what amount KI should be taken? Does the amount matter in preparing a solution of particular concentration?

Comment: Ingredients
1. Potassium iodide: 10 g
2. Distilled water: 100 ml
3. Iodine crystals: 5 g. Preparation: A. Dissolve 10 g potassium iodide in 100 ml of distilled water.
B. Slowly add 5 g iodine crystals, while shaking.
C. Filter and store in a tightly stoppered brown bottle.
This solution has the name of Lugol's iodine solution. As you can see, it has 0.0197 mol of iodine and 0.06 mol of potassium iodide.